# Return a dict object from Jinja2 macros

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a separate file for helper macros, so I import one when needed. Here is problematic macro:

```
{% macro row_cycler(tiles) -%}
    {%- set row1 = [] -%}
    {%- set row2 = [] -%}
    {%- set row3 = [] -%}
    {%- set row4 = [] -%}
    {%- set rows = cycler(row1, row2, row3, row4) -%}
    {% for column in tiles|batch(4) -%}
        {% for tile in column -%}
            {%- do rows.next().append(tile) -%}
        {%- endfor %}
    {%- endfor %}
    {{ dict(row1=row1, row2=row2, row3=row3, row4=row4) }}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Seems it returns dict, but it's not. It returns "markupsafe.Markup object", it leads to something that:

```
UndefinedError: 'markupsafe.Markup object' has no attribute 'itervalues'
```

and so on. How can I force Jinja to return dict without converting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, macros can only return template snippets (in the form of `Markup` objects), not Python objects like dictionaries. Use Python code for that instead; add a function to the items passed into the template or add a template global.

In your case it looks as if you are re-implementing the [`slice()` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#slice), so perhaps that's not even needed in this case.

Comment: Eh, I found that: _Functions returning template data (macros, super, self.BLOCKNAME) return safe markup always._
I use this code directly (in templates) with no problem, but in many templates, so I wanted to reduce it into the macro.
Thank you for explain.

Answer (score 7):

I overcame a similar problem in Ansible (it has a built-in filter `from_json`) by returning a `json` string and parsing it back into a dictionary:

```
{% macro get_dict() -%}
  {%- set d = dict() -%}
  {{- d.update(foo="bar") -}}
  {{- d.update(spam="eggs") -}}
  {{- d|to_json -}}
{%- endmacro %}

{% set d = get_dict()|from_json %}
{% for key, value in d.items() %}
  {{- key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

If not using Ansible, one could easily define the `from_json` filter, something like below (where `env` is an instance of `jinja2.Environment`):

```
def from_json(val):
    return json.loads(val)

env.filters["from_json"] = from_json
```

Comment: I don't see any `from_json` in [Jinja2 built-in filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#builtin-filters), I guess you are referring to Ansible. Of course, one could define a custom filter.

Comment: @haridsv you're right, I used Ansible. I've updated the answer to mention that, thanks!

Comment: Added a solution when not using Ansible.